# How do I deserialize the user in my graphQL context

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, graphql, passport.js

I have a `express` server in which I am using `express-graphql`.  I am also authenticating with `passport` and `passport-google-oauth20`.

I am setting up my `graphQl` without the context:

```
router.use(graphqlHTTP({
  schema,
  graphiql: true
}));
```

Which means that the `request` is passed into my `resolver` as the `context`.

```
const rootResolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (obj, args, context) => {
      console.log(context.headers.cookie);
      return "hello"
    }
  }
};
```

I can see the `cookie` from the request.  How do use the `cookie` that get to `deserialize` the user?  `passport` typically does this for me, but in this case I need to call the `deserialize` function outside of the `passport` lifecycle.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a `user` attached to the `request` and it is already `deserialized`.  Inside the `resolver`, all that needs to be done is access the `user`:

```
const rootResolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (obj, args, context) => {
      console.log(context.user);
      return "hellllo"
    }
  }
};
```

And now you can use it anyway that you want.